# SSH from WSL get hung

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to ssh from a WSL instance (an Ubuntu one) to an external CentOS machine (accessible through a VPN connected from the Windows host).
I already configured the key pairs and they seems to work.

When I start a command through ssh, it works:

```
$ ssh host uptime
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
 10:28:22 up 64 days, 21:16,  5 users,  load average: 0.04, 0.01, 0.00
```

but when I try to just get a terminal, it just hung without offering the prompt. Looking at the debug information does not seem to be informative:

```
$ ssh -vvvv host
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "host" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to host [172.16.10.20] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to host:22 as 'user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from host
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 1581/3072
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:FAKE2w5EZDJTIjoQfEbnBB9dRfjPM4mJ19umVRufake
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from host
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 172.16.10.20
debug1: Host 'host' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 1501/3072
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:FAKE5zXGf2hAcMAIokDJoSXoYSxm7ZUq/uJRM67fake
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)


debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:FAKE5zXGf2hAcMAIokDJoSXoYSxm7ZUq/uJRM67fake
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:FAKE5zXGf2hAcMAIokDJoSXoYSxm7ZUq/uJRM67fake
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:FAKE5zXGf2hAcMAIokDJoSXoYSxm7ZUq/uJRM67fake
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ssh-rsa SHA256:FAKE5zXGf2hAcMAIokDJoSXoYSxm7ZUq/uJRM67fake
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to host([172.16.10.20]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env WSL_DISTRO_NAME
debug3: Ignored env LANGUAGE
debug3: Ignored env NAME
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug1: Sending env LANG = C.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env WSL_INTEROP
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = C.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env WSLENV
debug3: Ignored env LOCALE
debug1: Sending env LC_ALL = C.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env HOSTTYPE
debug3: Ignored env _
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

After the last line, the ssh blocks and the only way it exit is to kill the process from another terminal. No prompt, no response to any blindly typed command... but the authentication worked.

I'm also trying to get rsync to work between those two hosts and I'm getting a similar behavior. Probably both issues are connected. In the rsync scenario, I can see it manages to get the file listing, but it also blocks and do not perform any file copy:

```
$ rsync -vvvvv --recursive host:devel/software/ .
cmd=<NULL> machine=host user=<NULL> path=devel/software/
cmd[0]=ssh cmd[1]=host cmd[2]=rsync cmd[3]=--server cmd[4]=--sender cmd[5]=-vvvvvre.iLsfxC cmd[6]=. cmd[7]=devel/software/
opening connection using: ssh host rsync --server --sender -vvvvvre.iLsfxC . devel/software/  (8 args)
msg checking charset: UTF-8
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
FILE_STRUCT_LEN=24, EXTRA_LEN=4
(Server) Protocol versions: remote=31, negotiated=30
(Client) Protocol versions: remote=30, negotiated=30
FILE_STRUCT_LEN=24, EXTRA_LEN=4
receiving incremental file list
server_sender starting pid=28674
[sender] change_dir(/home/devel/user/devel/software)
[sender] make_file(.,*,0)
recv_file_name(.)
[sender] make_file(file1.py,*,2)
recv_file_name(file1.py)
[sender] make_file(.gitignore,*,2)
recv_file_name(.gitignore)
[sender] make_file(.git,*,2)
recv_file_name(.git)
[sender] make_file(readme.md,*,2)
recv_file_name(readme.md)
[sender] make_file(file2.py,*,2)
```

Any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: Looks like you're probably starting a session on the remote system, but it's not printing a prompt. There could be something in your .bashrc or similar files which is preventing the shell from starting properly.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but if that were the case, I should happen everywhere, but in standard ssh from other linux and windows machines works (checked with putty, OpenSSH and cygwin ssh). It should also work to do a blind `ls` and an `exit`, but these don't work either. And the `rsync` should not be hung either :-?